Using Pivot table to count if value is in multiple columns
I have an excel table where values (names) are entered in columns if they meet certain criteria.
I have pivot tables that count the number of times a specific value (name) appears in each column.
Is there a way to use a pivot table to provide a count if the value appears in either column? e.g. name appears twice in column C and then once in column D would give a count of 3.
I have looked at combining the pivot tables but since they each have different values in each I cant find a way to easily combine them.
Thanks in advance

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If the PivotTable itself cannot achieve your needs, you can try using Countif, countifs formulas.
